How to upload file to Spring MVC controller? Error: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
I am trying to upload a file to a Spring MVC controller. But it throw the exception when clicked on register button. Please help me to get it resolved. Thanks.
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report
Message Failed to parse multipart servlet request

Exception
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request
............
Root Cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided........

Here is the controller:
@Controller
@MultipartConfig
public class RegistrationController extends HttpServlet {
    @Autowired
    public EmployeeService employeeService;

@Controller
@MultipartConfig
public class RegistrationController extends HttpServlet{
   @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("register");
   mav.addObject("employee", new Employee());
   return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public MOdelAndView addUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, @RequestParam MultipartFile photo){
   employeeService.register(employee, photo);
   return new ModelAndView("register","msg","Employee registered successfully");
}
}

The register.jsp page:
<form:form id="regForm" modelAttribute="employee" action="registerProcess" method="post"
           enctype='multipart/form-data'>
...........
<tr>
                <td><form:label path="photo">Employee Photo</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input type="file" path="photo" name="photo" id="photo" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><form:button class="btn btn-primary" id="register" name="register">Register</form:button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>

Also, I have provided this in web.xml
  <filter>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

And application.properties,
   spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
   spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

and in context.xml inside resources
<Context allowCasualMultipartParsing="true"></Context>
I have tried already given answers in stackoverflow and other sites, but no change in error. Sometimes it's just threw 404.

In your code is a mess of spring mvc and servlets code.

Indeed. Remove extends HttpServlet from your Spring MVC controller class and adjust your research for the answer to focus on "How to upload to a Spring MVC controller?" instead of "How to upload to a Servlet?" because they are not the same.
